# C++ template/ostream operator question

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, ostream

trying to get the operator to work, but throwing me bunch of errors:

my header file

```
template <unsigned short n>
class Vector {
public:
    std::vector<float> coords;

    Vector();
    Vector(std::vector<float> crds);
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Vector& v);
};

template <unsigned short n>
Vector<n>::Vector() {
coords.assign(n, 0.0);
}

template <unsigned short n>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Vector<n>& v) {
out << "(" << v.coords[1] << " - " << v.coords[2] << ")";
return out;
}
```

test file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "vector.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
Vector<3> toomas;
cout << toomas;

}
```

error:

C:\CodeBlocks\kool\praks3\vector.h|14|warning: friend declaration 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Vector&)' declares a non-template function|

C:\CodeBlocks\kool\praks3\vector.h|14|note: (if this is not what you intended, make sure the function template has already been declared and add <> after the function name here) |

obj\Debug\test.o||In function `main':|

C:\CodeBlocks\kool\praks3\test.cpp|8|undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, Vector<(unsigned short)3> const&)'|

Comment: You shouldn't declare it a friend in the first place, because you are not accessing anything private. - Also a std::vector might be a bit heavyweight for a math Vector...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please look at the error, it says,

> friend declaration 'std::ostream&
>   operator<<(std::ostream&, const
>   Vector&)' declares a **non-template**
>   function|

That means you need to make the `operator<<` a template function.

So in the class, you've to declare it as:

```
template<unsigned short m> //<----note this: i.e make it template!
friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Vector<m>& v);
```

Then define it as,

```
template <unsigned short m>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Vector<m>& v) {
   out << "(" << v.coords[1] << " - " << v.coords[2] << ")";
   return out;
}
```

Comment: You mean **unsigned short m**

Comment: @Erik: No I mean, make it template. However, you can choose any name be it `m`, `a`,`b`. etc. but don't choose `n` because it's the argument of enclosing class template!

Comment: Yuck.  Why should `operator <<` for `Vector<m>` have access to privates of `Vector<n>`?

Comment: @Ben: You've a point. But I was explaining the friend part, and the error he is getting!

Comment: @Nawaz: You do actually mean **unsigned short m** :P - you used **unsigned int m** in declaration and **unsigned short m** in definition

Comment: @Erik: Oops.. I thought you were talking about `m` vs `n` thingy, when in fact it's `int` vs `short`. Anyway corrected!

Comment: @Nawaz: well this worked great, thanks, but i do not understand one thing..why doesn't the template before my `class Vector ` work for the ostream? why must i write the template twice, but for example i did not have to do that for my constructor.  i don't really understand the concept hehe. and why we are using m suddenly, but in constructors we use n.

Comment: @Jaanus: `template<unsigned short n>` is only for the class, not for the function inside it. If you want to make the function template as well, then you've to do as I said, or do as Ben's solution second is!

Answer (score 7):

Just define the friend function inside the class.

```
template <unsigned short n>
class Vector
{
public:
    std::vector<float> coords;

    Vector();
    Vector(std::vector<float> crds);
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Vector& v)
    {
        out << "(" << v.coords[1] << " - " << v.coords[2] << ")";
        return out;
    }
};

template <unsigned short n>
Vector<n>::Vector()
{
    coords.assign(n, 0.0);
}


int main()
{
    Vector<3> toomas;
    cout << toomas;
}
```

Tested: http://ideone.com/LDAR4

Or, declare the template function beforehand, using a forward prototype:

```
template <unsigned short n>
class Vector;

template <unsigned short n>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Vector<n>& v);

template <unsigned short n>
class Vector
{
public:
    std::vector<float> coords;

    Vector();
    Vector(std::vector<float> crds);
    friend std::ostream& operator << <>(std::ostream& out, const Vector& v);
};

template <unsigned short n>
Vector<n>::Vector()
{
    coords.assign(n, 0.0);
}

template <unsigned short n>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Vector<n>& v)
{
    out << "(" << v.coords[1] << " - " << v.coords[2] << ")";
    return out;
}
```

Tested: http://ideone.com/8eTeq

Comment: I've been reading this post as I have a very similar problem. Could you explain why ``ostream& operator <<`` needs to be initialized and defined inside the class? And also, why it has to be a friend function ?  For instance, I can overload operator ``+=`` and I don't have to give the definition inside my class, neither do I have to declare it as a friend. Why ``ostream& operator <<`` is so special?

Comment: @zorro47: It doesn't have to be a friend function.  OP wanted it that way.  On the other hand, your comment's comparison to `operator+=` is faulty.  First, `operator+=` overload CANNOT be a friend, and it CANNOT be a free function, it's required to be a non-static member.  Second, for `operator+=` the class instance is the left-hand operand, for `operator<<(ostream&, MyClass&)` the class instance is the right operand.  When the class instance is the right operand, you cannot provide the operator as a class member.

Comment: @zorro47: And right there in my answer has always been an example (second code block) of how to define `operator<<` outside the class, so why are you asking if that is possible?

Comment: The method you presented in the second block I figured out on my own as well but it does not work every time I try to apply to my code. However, when I define it as friend inside the class it suddenly starts working. This happens only with ``ostream&``  Strange to me. That is why I was asking.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue