# How to do right template outputs in c++

Tags: c++, templates, operators

i have this error in MSVS project, in this part of code

```
ostream& getStream(ostream& out)
    {
        for (Node* temp = head; temp; temp = temp->next)
            out << temp->info << " ";
        return out;
    }
```

Error C2679 binary"<<": no operator was found that accepts the right operand of type " T " (or there is no acceptable conversion)

```
#pragma once
#ifndef _LIST_H_
#define _LIST_H_
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class MyList
{
protected :
    struct Node
    {
        T info;
        Node* next;
        Node(T info, Node* next = 0) :
            info(info),
            next(next)
        {}
    };

    Node* head;
    ostream& getStream(ostream& out)
    {
        for (Node* temp = head; temp; temp = temp->next)
            out << temp->info << " ";
        return out;
    }
public:
    MyList();
    ~MyList();

    template <class T1>
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, MyList<T1>& list);

    void Insert(T info, int index);
    int Count();
    void Remove(int index);
    void PopFront();
    void PushFront(T Data);
    void PopBack();
    void PushBack(T Data);
};

template <class T>
MyList<T>::MyList():
    head(0)
{}

template <class T>
MyList<T>::~MyList()
{
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        Node* help = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = help;
    }
}


template <class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, MyList<T>& list)
{
    return list.getStream(out);
}

template <class T>
void MyList<T>::Insert(T info, int index)
{
    if (Count() < index || index < 0) throw 1;

    if (index == 0)
    {
        head = new Node(info, head);
        return;
    }
    Node* current = head;
    for (int i = 1; i < index; current = current->next, i++);
    current->next = new Node(info, current->next);
}

template <class T>
void MyList<T>::Remove(int index)
{
    if (Count() <= index || index < 0) throw 1;
    if (index == 0)
    {
        Node* help = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = help;
        return;
    }
    Node* current = head;
    for (int i = 1; i < index; current = current->next, i++);
    Node* help = current->next;
    current->next = help->next;
    delete help;
}

template <class T>
void MyList<T>::PopFront()
{
    if (head == 0) return;
    Node* help = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete help;

}

template<class T>
void MyList<T>::PushFront(T Data)
{
    head = new Node(Data, head);
}

template<class T>
void MyList<T>::PopBack()
{
    if (head == 0)return;

    if (Count() == 1)
    {
        delete head;
        head = 0;
    }

    Node* curr;

    for (curr = head; curr->next->next != 0; curr = curr->next);

    delete curr->next;
    curr->next = 0;
}

template<class T>
void MyList<T>::PushBack(T Data)
{
    Node* curr;
    for (curr = head; curr->next != 0; curr = curr->next);
    curr->next = new Node(Data);
}

template <class T>
int MyList<T>::Count()
{
    int count = 0;
    for (Node* current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next, count++);
    return count;
}



#endif // !_LIST_H_
```

this is declaration of my class
i have no ideas how to fix it,
big thank to you if you will try to help me
sory if have bad description, im only starting

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You have an instantiation of that template somewhere in code that you did not post. What is `T` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284473/c-template-ostream-operator-question

Comment: i dont use this class in my code, this file dont compile.

Comment: the code you posted does not compile due to missing includes and not fully qualified names, but otherwise it compiles without errors: https://ideone.com/e.js/ng9xqT. Please include a [mcve]. It is not possible to get that error with only this code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284473/c-template-ostream-operator-question it is for operator<< i try to do function that belongs to class

Comment: this is compile it in c++ dbg online, i but not on my laptop

Comment: i add all code i have in a file

Comment: here was my bad, specification of this class broke the code, sorry, thank all of you

Comment: the code you posted should also compile on your laptop, there must be more code to get that error. Or your compiler is broken

Comment: You are right in one of its descendant i have implementation mistake

Answer (score -1):

one of descendant of my class have bad implementation of operator<<, and that class jump me to this problem